# Running Balance in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get a running balance using SQL Server 2012

Here is what I got so far...

```
DECLARE @Transactions TABLE
(
    Amount decimal (18,2),
    TransactionId uniqueidentifier,
    AccountId uniqueidentifier,
    TransactionDate date
)

DECLARE @AccountId uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT 3224.99, NEWID(), @AccountId, '2013-06-02'

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT 18.99, NEWID(), NEWID(), '2013-06-14'

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT -8.99, NEWID(), @AccountId, '2013-06-14' 

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT -6.99, NEWID(), @AccountId, '2013-06-14'

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT -22.14, NEWID(), @AccountId, '2014-11-09'

INSERT INTO @Transactions (Amount, TransactionId, AccountId, TransactionDate)
SELECT -84.99, NEWID(), @AccountId, '2013-06-09'


SELECT  SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate, TransactionId) as [RunningBalance],
        Amount
FROM @Transactions 
WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC
```

Results are

```
RunningBalance                          Amount
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
3101.88                                 -22.14
3133.01                                 -6.99
3124.02                                 -8.99
3140.00                                 -84.99
3224.99                                 3224.99
```

My goal is to have RunningBalance show each balance, even if its the same day, each row should have its own balance

As you can see, the 2nd row is not coming up correctly and I believe it is because I also have a 2nd account Id that is conflicting with it, but assumed the WHERE statement would remove it..

I can remove the ORDER BY, however I am wanting my list newest transaction first, as final query will have paging, and I have tried something like this.. but balance is off...

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY TransactionDate, TransactionId) as [RunningBalance],
        Amount, TransactionDate
FROM @Transactions 
WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
) AS Results
ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC




RunningBalance                          Amount                                  TransactionDate
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------
3101.88                                 -22.14                                  2014-11-09
3131.01                                 -8.99                                   2013-06-14
3124.02                                 -6.99                                   2013-06-14
3140.00                                 -84.99                                  2013-06-09
3224.99                                 3224.99                                 2013-06-02
```

I'm not too sure what the problem is...

Comment: If two rows have the same date, I have no idea how you are expecting to know which one was first. Also if the rows assign NEWID() to TransactionID, I don't see why you need to ORDER BY this inside the aggregate - what purpose could this possibly serve?

Comment: I was thinking adding Id would allow it calculate it even if the values are same date.. it does but not correctly, if I removed the Id the 2 transactions with same date would have the exact same amount

Comment: You need something else (an identity column, a sequence number, a time column, or use datetime instead of date, or something) to allow you to distinguish two values on the same day and in which order they occurred.

Comment: Oh duh, that would help.. I do have a CreatedOn column, instead of Id I used that and it worked perfect.. amounts match up correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ordering by TransactionId (a meaningless GUID value that has no bearing on when the row was inserted), you need to determine proper order in some other way. Since you have a CreatedOn column that stores the date/time the row was inserted, you should add that to your order by to generate the correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering your running balance differently than your results, so the rows don't coincide the way you think they should:

```
SELECT  SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate, TransactionId) as [RunningBalance],
        Amount
FROM @Transactions 
WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
ORDER BY TransactionDate, TransactionId
```

If you want to `ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC` then do so in your running balance too:

```
SELECT  SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC, TransactionId) as [RunningBalance],
        Amount
FROM @Transactions 
WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
```

You can't have a meaningful running balance with disparate `ORDER BY` criteria.

Comment: I did that because I'm going to be paging the list and I want the newer transactions first

Comment: I see what you are saying though, even if I remove the ORDER BY after the WHERE the results match up.. but problem is when I try to order by it newer first, numbers don't match up correctly, i'll revise question to show it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to use is ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.

```
SELECT TransactionDate
,Amount
,SUM(Amount) OVER (
    ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    ) AS [RunningBalance]
FROM @Transactions
WHERE AccountId = @AccountId
```